# Función con nested data en variables específicas (map en R)

Tags: r

Me hallo trabajando en una nested data con R y me he requerido utilizar el entorno tidyverse por no romper la estructura del proyecto. Pondré mi ejemplo con `mtcars`.

Mi estructura básica sería parecida a esta:

```
library(tidyverse);

mtcars %>%
 group_by(cyl,carb) %>%
 nest()
```

En la que una o más variables son la clasificación y luego están las demás variables que me interesan se hallan dentro del apartado `data`

Mi necesidad es recrear solo en las variables `hp` i `wt` dentro del apartado `data` una función cualquiera. Solo quiero trabajar con unas variables concretas dentro del apartado data. He probado al menos de sacarlas todas pero ni siquiera la puedo aplicar en general

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl,carb) %>% nest() 
  mutate(difference = map(data$hp, ~diff(.x)/.x) )
```

Comment: Bienvenido Aitor. No termino de entender lo que necesitas. Algunas preguntas que podrían ayudar a responderte ¿Qué denotas con `Xi`? ¿Una fila, una columna o un grupo o categoría? ¿Para qué necesitas anidar los datos con `nest()`?

Comment: Si, ya veo, ahora que releo la pregunta no acaba de estar bien formulada del todo. Voy a probar de corregirla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución es anidar dos map uno para recorrer todos los data.frame  y otro para aplicar una función sobre cada columna

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl,carb) %>% 
nest() %>%
mutate(difference = map(data, function(x) map(x,function(y) diff(y/y))))


  cyl  carb data             difference      
 <dbl> <dbl> <list>           <list>          
1     6     4 <tibble [4 x 9]> <named list [9]>
2     4     1 <tibble [5 x 9]> <named list [9]>
3     6     1 <tibble [2 x 9]> <named list [9]>
4     8     2 <tibble [4 x 9]> <named list [9]>
5     8     4 <tibble [6 x 9]> <named list [9]>
6     4     2 <tibble [6 x 9]> <named list [9]>
7     8     3 <tibble [3 x 9]> <named list [9]>
8     6     6 <tibble [1 x 9]> <named list [9]>
9     8     8 <tibble [1 x 9]> <named list [9]>
```

El resultado que obtienes es una serie de lista con el resultado de la operación realiza en cada columna dentro de cada data.frame

Comment: el problema de esta solución es que solo me funcionaría para un solo caso (la variable hp), no me ayudaría a hacer hp wt i quizas otras. La idea básica está bien pero mi problema es que necesito operar con varios a la vez

Comment: Realice la modificación en el código para el ejemplo que mencionas ahora la función se aplica para cada uno de las columnas dentro de cada data.frame esta respuesta es una versión general de la antes propuesta